# Want to use value of a particular Key in a Multidimensional array In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array is like this:

```
$x= Array(

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => id
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] =>names
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 1
    )
)
```

I want to write a statement that says if the value of the key[0]== id, then do something; else if the value of the key[0]== names, do something else.
Is there a way i can do that?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess loop through the array an use a simple if statement ?!

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Writing code would be a good start.

Comment: `foreach($x as $y) if($y[0] == 'id') ...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use **foreach** loop

```
    foreach($x as $key){  
         if ($key[0] == 'id') {  
              echo "Your id code will be here";  
         } else if ($key[0] == 'names') {  
              echo "Your names code will be here";  
         }    
    }
```